# How to access google maps api in China

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using google maps api to get user location in my IBM Mobilefirst project and it is working fine as expected in all the countries except china.I know this is because china has blocked access to google apis in their country.Is there any workaround that I can make so that the application works even in china. I have given the code snippet below for reference.

This is the script I have in head

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBaKx9iQrPQuOmAc2DkMRgjFdT0_XTdbmE&sensor=false&v=3&libraries=geometry"></script>
```

javascript code

```
function getLocation() {
    busy = new WL.BusyIndicator ();
    busy.show();
    if (navigator.geolocation) {

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError,options);
    } else { 
        alert( "Geolocation is not supported");}
    }

function showPosition(pos) {

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude,pos.coords.longitude);
    latitude=pos.coords.latitude;
    longitude=pos.coords.longitude;
    geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var addresscomponent=results[0].address_components;
            var addresslength=addresscomponent.length;
            for(var i=0;i<addresslength;i++){
                if(addresscomponent[i].types[0]=='country'){
                    countryname=addresscomponent[i].short_name;
                }
                else if(addresscomponent[i].types[0]=='locality'){
                    cityname=addresscomponent[i].short_name;
                }
            }
}

function showError(error) {
    alert(error);
    busy.hide(); 
       }
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Why can't I access Google Maps APIs from China?

The Google Maps APIs are served within China from the domain maps.google.cn. This domain does not support https. When making requests to the Google Maps APIs from China, please replace https://maps.googleapis.com with http://maps.google.cn.

For example:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA

would become:

> http://maps.google.cn/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA

reference :[Google FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq?hl=en#china_ws_access)

**Update**
For country use this:

```js
$.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json/", function (data) {
        var country = data.country_name;//your country
        alert(country);
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: but how will I know before getting the location that if the user is from china or from other parts of the world?

Comment: `$.getJSON("http://freegeoip.net/json/", function (data) {
    var country = data.country_name;
   alert(country);//check this and use that code.
});`

Comment: Thanks.Let me try with this.

Comment: sure I am just working on it will comment back on the status..Thanks for your timely response. I guess I wouldn't be needing to hit the google api if I am able to get the country from this service. only for India I need to get city for other countries I just need the country name and country code

Comment: unfortunately not working for me as well URL IS NOT WORKING :https://maps.google.cn/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Vish&key= Google_API_Key --------URL IS WORKING https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Vish&key= Google_API_Key

Comment: Update - None of this will work in China i.e. using googleapis.com or google.cn. This year in Feb 2020, Google has stopped the .cn domain and asked to use the .com one, but even that doesnt work. I have tried this change in China location and when contacted Google, they redirect you to their Google maps documenation which says China is in prohibited country list, so they cant do anything.
Also, some users report that it has worked at times, but there have been dropped connection. So, its 100% not reliable at all.

Comment: @whyAto8 See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62986634/902582

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer stopped working from Feb 2020 as Google China stopped supporting the Chinese Google Maps API (https://maps.googleapis.cn/maps/api/js).

I have found a hack and it has been working fine for me.

Basically,

1. Download https://google.cn/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY as a Javascript file.
2. Open it and replace `maps.google.cn` with `google.cn`.
   Host the modified Javascript on your website and use the API normally.
3. THIS IS VERY IMPORTANT: after some time the Javascript will expire and stop working, so you have to start from step 1 again. I ended up automating the process in my Rails app.
4. OPTIONAL BUT ALSO IMPORTANT: you may want to figure out a way to restrict the access to the modified Javascript. Otherwise someone may abuse it and it’s you who needs to pay the bill.

Detailed blog post with demo and screenshot: https://dingyu.me/blog/google-maps-api-china

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```js
if((pos.coords.latitude>=37 && pos.coords.latitude<=47)&& (pos.coords.latitude>=110 && pos.coords.latitude<=123))
{

//china
var googleGeocoding="http://maps.google.cn/maps/api/geocode/json?language=en&latlng=" + pos.coords.latitude + "," + pos.coords.longitude + "&key=" + Google_API_Key;
}else {
  
var googleGeocoding="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?language=en&latlng=" + pos.coords.latitude + "," + pos.coords.longitude + "&key=" + Google_API_Key;
}
```

As you can see...china is big country... but approximately lat lon is 37~47 , 110~123... http://www.latlong.net

It is not exactly check china or not but...if you are not china...you can access "http://maps.google.cn/"

So It is no problem...

Answer (score 0):

Whithout call position API or other external services:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[key]"></script>
<script>
    //Fallback pour google Map api
    window.google || document.write('<script src="http://maps.google.cn/maps/api/js?key=[key]">\x3C/script>');
</script>
```