# Open google map in china

Tags: angular

I have an application that uses https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/index.html. And I want to use it in china I found that i have to change the url to https://maps.google.cn/maps/api/js but i don't know how and where. I have try passing it to the Module by setting the region but it still doesn't work, does anyone have any other suggestions

Answer (score 0):

see workaround here -  use http instead of https.
[How to access google maps api in China](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33802180/how-to-access-google-maps-api-in-china)